# JavaScript/Typescript Declaring Object with Quoted Key for MongoDB '$push' Property

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm trying to prepare the data for add an element into the nested array in MongoDB. I'm doing this is typescript:

```
var data = {$push:{"foo.12.bar":{
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2,        // the right hand side values identified above the code
         ...
}}};
```

When I write this "foo.12.bar", it works fine. But what I want to do is putting this "foo.12.bar" value in a variable and makes it changeable.

This didn't work:

```
var propString = "foo.12.bar";

var data = {$push:{propString:{
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2,        // the right hand side values identified above the code
         ...
}}};
```

I'm not able to write any variable name after the $push property. How can I solve that ?

Comment: Use `[propString]`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan it works perfect thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use bracket notation for that.

```
var propString = "foo.12.bar";

var data = {$push:{}};

data[propString] = {
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2
};
```